# Android:CalledFromWrongThreadException in AsyncTask in the onProgressUpdate function

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is a very simple program which calls the asynctask on button click, which changes the textview.

But on button click it gives a CalledFromWrongException.

```
public class FragmentC extends Fragment {
public FragmentC() {
    }
public View contentViewC;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    contentViewC = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_b, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) contentViewC.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MainActivity.filepath != "Nothing") {
                Frequency getFreq=new Frequency();
                getFreq.execute();
       }

        }

    });
    return contentViewC;
}
private class Frequency extends AsyncTask<Void, Float, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            onProgressUpdate();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
      textToChange.setText("Demo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also can you attach the exceptions with the post along with only necessary code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont call `onProgressUpdate()` directly

You just call `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()`, then `AsynchTask` call `onProgressUpdate()` in the UI thread.

```
In Android only in main thread we update the UI
```

For more check this   [onProgressUpdate() documnet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)